# O que este código anti-robo em Javascript faz?

Tags: javascript, scraping

O que este código anti-robo em Javascript faz?

```html
<html><head></head><body onload="challenge();">
<script>
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('1 6(){2.3=\'4=5; 0-7=8; 9=/\';a.b.c()}',13,13,'max|function|document|cookie|Anti-Robot|ee2c23967cffbc6dff69153929fd8155017def99|challenge|age|86400|path|window|location|reload'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script>
</body></html>
```

Há algumas semanas vi uma discussão acerca de *Parsear* sites onde um dos membros postou este código `anti-robo` também foi relatado que o software utilizado por ele durante o processo ficou um tempo exorbitante tentando baixar uma unica pagina e no final só havia este código anti-robo e nenhum conteúdo da página desejada, infelizmente não tenho mais o *link* da discussão nem do site cuja a página possui este anti-robo.

**Obs:** Foi informado que ele estava usando o software *PhantomJS* configurado com um *user-agent* (o que em tese deveria maquia-lo para que se parece com o chrome/firefox).

**Obs2:** Esta é a formatação original do código

Comment: está apenas codificado... há vários sites que decodificam retornando o resultado compilado pela função eval(). Faça vc mesmo nesse site e veja o que retorna: http://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker

Comment: @DanielOmine não consegui fazer o unpack, eu gostaria de uma explicação do código mesmo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O código original é:

```
function challenge() {
    document.cookie = 'Anti-Robot=ee2c23967cffbc6dff69153929fd8155017def99; max-age=86400; path=/';
    window.location.reload()
}
```

Ele basicamente define o cookie `Anti-Robot` e depois atualiza a página.

Provavelmente o cookie é usado posteriormente verificado no servidor para evitar que um formulário seja submetido ou um request seja feito por scripts automatizados.

Talvez o valor do cookie seja invalidado a cada requisição e gerado novamente, como um tipo *token* com duração limitada. Esta e uma técnica comum em diversos frameworks de diferentes linguagens para evitar *requests* duplicados (usuário clica duas vezes no botão, o navegador faz 2 submits, mas o segundo é ignorado pelo servidor porque o token já foi usado no primeiro request) e algumas brechas de segurança.

Porém, seria precisa avaliar o código no contexto para ter certeza.

Comment: como consegui chegar a este resultado? como o browser consegue chegar a este resultado?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Para descompilar usei o unpacker que o Daniel Omine sugeriu. Você precisa colar lá apenas a linha do eval. Já o *browser* executa o que tem dentro do eval e lá tem uma função que decodifica o código.